# Are Java (security) Policy employed at build/compile time?

Tags: java, security, intellij-idea

I wonder if already, at time of `javac`-compiling of some **untrusted code**, it is necessary/sensible to use [Java policy files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/PolicyFiles.html) to avoid compromising my system, i.e. during the compilation of the code?

I wonder this because at least as an option in IntelliJ IDEA there is an option to set JVM options for the build (which could be set to `-Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy==/home/user/.java.policy`). The effect however seems to me to be with regards with the executing of java bytecode during the build (i.e. because of using build systems like ANT, Maven.....)

My take on the matter has been that Java (security) policy is something that matters at runtime only and that -except for bugs in the `javac`- the compilation even of untrusted code is safe. So that the Java security policy files are only a matter for the runtime JVM which executes the resulting bytecode.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. Using a security manager when compiling won't protect you against anything except the compiler, and you're already trusting that more than you can possibly imagine, just by using it.